# How to avoid fails extraction array?

Tags: typescript

I have the folloeing code:

```
public drawSourceIdRegistryPolygons = new ExtendedMap<number, number[]>();

   this.state.drawSourceIdRegistryPolygons.set(registryId, [
        ...this.state.drawSourceIdRegistryPolygons.get(registryId),
        ...drawRegistryPolygonsId,
    ]);
```

How to secure case when `this.state.drawSourceIdRegistryPolygons.get(registryId)` returns undefined or null?

Is it solution?

```
...(this.state.drawSourceIdRegistryPolygons.get(registryId) || [])
```

[Please refer a simplified TS Playground reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG0CMAaATCgzAXQNwFgAoUSAIzggDsQB3CAWSgAcAKASgMNIDoBncFqjQciREhADGFBN1lQUEHgHMBSAAxq2eUYQkB7Srz2huwPUpYSOQA)

Comment: `??` would be clearer I think than `||` (`x ?? y` means use `x` is x is neither null nor undefined, otherwise use `y`)

Comment: Yep, that's a correct solution. @user13314476